# How to get the average number of Item Sold per week in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table of sold item which has following columns like

```
SoldItemID
SoldID 
SoldAmount
DateOfPurchase
DateOfActivation 
CreatedDate
```

How to get the average number of Item sold Per week in SQL?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I've removed all those dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: do you know about GROUP BY?  You can use that, but you need to create a 'week number' possibly bt using DATEDIFF on DateOfPurchase  against a reference date

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: What dbms is this? You'll be grouping by 'week number', and the choice of dbms decides how you get week number.

Comment: its mysql db i need the logoc how to get the result average number of items sold per week.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party, but just in case other people are looking, this might work:

```sql
    select date_part('week', transaction_date) week_of_the_year, item_id,
    avg(sold_qty) from your_table group by 1, 2 order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL SERVER

```
WITH CTE AS(

    SELECT 
        *
    FROM (
        VALUES  
            ('2018-08-23', 'A', 10),
            ('2018-08-23', 'B', 10),
            ('2018-08-24', 'A', 14),
            ('2018-08-31', 'A', 8),
            ('2018-08-31', 'B', 10)
        ) as list (Date_, Item, Amount)
)

select 
    WKnum, MIN(Date_), MAX(Date_), Item, AVG(Amount)    
from(
    select 
        *,
        DATEPART(WK, Date_) WKnum
    from CTE
    ) as A
group by WKnum, Item
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with unkown dbms. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query: it will work on sql server

```
select datepart(week,DateOfPurchase),avg(item)
from
(
select DateOfPurchase,count(SoldItemID) item
from tablename group by DateOfPurchase) a
group by datepart(week,DateOfPurchase)
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with unknown dbms. At least tell us which dbms this is for.